# Solucion a NullPointerException en Java

Tags: java, nullpointerexception

Estoy teniendo problemas con mi código en  Java. El error al parecer se encuentra al intentar abrir un imagen y enviarla a un `JLabel` al realizarlo  me manda un `NullPointerException`, esto lo estoy haciendo con `JFileChooser`.

Este es el código que estoy utilizando para hacer la acción antes mencionada

```
public void botonGuardarFtActionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) { 
    JFileChooser file = new JFileChooser();

    FileNameExtensionFilter fil = new FileNameExtensionFilter( "JPG y PNG","jpg","png") ;
    file.setFileFilter(fil); 
    int seleccion = file.showOpenDialog(null);

    // Si el usuario, pincha en aceptar
    if (seleccion == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
        fichero = file.getSelectedFile();


        try { 
            ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon(fichero.toString());

            Icon img = new ImageIcon(icon.getImage().getScaledInstance(150, 200,
                    Image.SCALE_DEFAULT)); 

            lblFoto.setIcon(img);

        } catch (Exception ex) {

            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Error abriendo la imagen " + ex);
            System.out.println(ex);

        }

    }
}
```

Espero y alguien me pueda ayudar a solucionar este error.

Comment: En que linea exacta da  el error? y de que tipo es la variable fichero?

Comment: @LcsGrz En lblFoto.setIcon(img) . La variable fichero es de tipo File

Comment: estas intanciando en algun momento lblFoto? verifica eso, tambien verifica si img es la que esta null

Comment: @LcsGrz Gracias ya logre resolverlo. Al parecer el error era al instanciar el JLabel que recibia la imagen

Comment: @AarónFlores por ello es importante siempre tratar de crear un [mcve]